# How do I get my text-based adventure game to display one cell at a time in UITableView?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, game-development

I'm making a text-based adventure game for the iPhone in Xcode. I want to make my game like the mobile game Lifeline (it'll be vastly different though in terms of plot, animations, UI, etc.); however, I'm struggling with a problem. I don't know how to make my UITableView generate cells underneath each other after the user (the person playing my text-based adventure game) makes a decision.

(And yes, I've been learning from Angela Wu's Udemy course as you might be able to tell from the story texts. Fret not, I'm not copying her stuff, I'm just using it to practise my coding skills so that I can move onto my own app.)

Anyhow, instead of my story showing sequentially (one table cell after another after the user makes decisions), I keep making my code generate all of the story cells at once when the app loads up, and I'm not sure how to change that. I suspect I have to edit my UITableViewDataSource functions accordingly, but I have no idea where to begin with that.

How do I make my UITableView generate the next story underneath the old story when the user makes a decision?

I'm using Xcode version 12.4 and UIKit instead of SpriteKit.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice1Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice2Button: UIButton!
    
    var storyNumber = 0
    
    var stories: [Story] = [
        Story(
            title: "Your car has blown a tire on a winding road in the middle of nowhere with no cell phone reception. You decide to hitchhike. A rusty pickup truck rumbles to a stop next to you. A man with a wide brimmed hat with soulless eyes opens the passenger door for you and asks: 'Need a ride, boy?'.",
            choice1: "I'll hop in. Thanks for the help!", choice1Destination: 2,
            choice2: "Better ask him if he's a murderer first.", choice2Destination: 1
        ),
        Story(
            title: "He nods slowly, unfazed by the question.",
            choice1: "At least he's honest. I'll climb in.", choice1Destination: 2,
            choice2: "Wait, I know how to change a tire.", choice2Destination: 3
        ),
        Story(
            title: "As you begin to drive, the stranger starts talking about his relationship with his mother. He gets angrier and angrier by the minute. He asks you to open the glovebox. Inside you find a bloody knife, two severed fingers, and a cassette tape of Elton John. He reaches for the glove box.",
            choice1: "I love Elton John! Hand him the cassette tape.", choice1Destination: 5,
            choice2: "It's him or me! You take the knife and stab him.", choice2Destination: 4
        ),
        Story(
            title: "What? Such a cop out! Did you know traffic accidents are the second leading cause of accidental death for most adult age groups?",
            choice1: "The", choice1Destination: 0,
            choice2: "End", choice2Destination: 0
        ),
        Story(
            title: "As you smash through the guardrail and careen towards the jagged rocks below you reflect on the dubious wisdom of stabbing someone while they are driving a car you are in.",
            choice1: "The", choice1Destination: 0,
            choice2: "End", choice2Destination: 0
        ),
        Story(
            title: "You bond with the murderer while crooning verses of 'Can you feel the love tonight'. He drops you off at the next town. Before you go he asks you if you know any good places to dump bodies. You reply: 'Try the pier.'",
            choice1: "The", choice1Destination: 0,
            choice2: "End", choice2Destination: 0
        )
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "StoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")
        
        updateUI()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        var  userChoice = sender.currentTitle!
        
        if userChoice == stories[storyNumber].choice1 {
            storyNumber = stories[storyNumber].choice1Destination
        }
        
        if userChoice == stories[storyNumber].choice2 {
            storyNumber = stories[storyNumber].choice2Destination
        }
        
        updateUI()
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        
        choice1Button.setTitle(stories[storyNumber].choice1, for: .normal)
        choice2Button.setTitle(stories[storyNumber].choice2, for: .normal)
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stories.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryCell
        cell.label.text = stories[indexPath.row].title
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand, you need a separate var like userChoices that contains the users choices. Each choice is appended to it. The table displays the userChoices not the stories.

Comment: I thank you for your help. I've been thinking a lot about what you've said, and I think you're right. Though, I'm having so much trouble trying to code your idea. Could you give me an idea of what I'm meant to write? Sorry about my persistence, I'm fairly new to coding and coding in Swift. Any amount of help will go a long way as I'm quite confident you've pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice1Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice2Button: UIButton!
    
    var storyNumber = 0
    
    // This array contains all the possibilities
    let stories: [Story] = [
        Story(
            title: "Your car has blown a tire on a winding road in the middle of nowhere with no cell phone reception. You decide to hitchhike. A rusty pickup truck rumbles to a stop next to you. A man with a wide brimmed hat with soulless eyes opens the passenger door for you and asks: 'Need a ride, boy?'.",
            choice1: "I'll hop in. Thanks for the help!", choice1Destination: 2,
            choice2: "Better ask him if he's a murderer first.", choice2Destination: 1
        ),
        Story(
            title: "He nods slowly, unfazed by the question.",
            choice1: "At least he's honest. I'll climb in.", choice1Destination: 2,
            choice2: "Wait, I know how to change a tire.", choice2Destination: 3
        ),
        Story(
            title: "As you begin to drive, the stranger starts talking about his relationship with his mother. He gets angrier and angrier by the minute. He asks you to open the glovebox. Inside you find a bloody knife, two severed fingers, and a cassette tape of Elton John. He reaches for the glove box.",
            choice1: "I love Elton John! Hand him the cassette tape.", choice1Destination: 5,
            choice2: "It's him or me! You take the knife and stab him.", choice2Destination: 4
        ),
        Story(
            title: "What? Such a cop out! Did you know traffic accidents are the second leading cause of accidental death for most adult age groups?",
            choice1: "The", choice1Destination: 0,
            choice2: "End", choice2Destination: 0
        ),
        Story(
            title: "As you smash through the guardrail and careen towards the jagged rocks below you reflect on the dubious wisdom of stabbing someone while they are driving a car you are in.",
            choice1: "The", choice1Destination: 0,
            choice2: "End", choice2Destination: 0
        ),
        Story(
            title: "You bond with the murderer while crooning verses of 'Can you feel the love tonight'. He drops you off at the next town. Before you go he asks you if you know any good places to dump bodies. You reply: 'Try the pier.'",
            choice1: "The", choice1Destination: 0,
            choice2: "End", choice2Destination: 0
        )
    ]
    
    // This will containe the user stories
    var userStories: [Story] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        userStories = [stories[0]] // Start user at story 0
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "StoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")
        
        updateUI()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        var  userChoice = sender.currentTitle!
        
        if userChoice == stories[storyNumber].choice1 {
            storyNumber = stories[storyNumber].choice1Destination
        }
        
        if userChoice == stories[storyNumber].choice2 {
            storyNumber = stories[storyNumber].choice2Destination
        }
        
        // Add the new story to user stories
        userStories.append(stories[storyNumber])
        
        updateUI()
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        
        choice1Button.setTitle(stories[storyNumber].choice1, for: .normal)
        choice2Button.setTitle(stories[storyNumber].choice2, for: .normal)
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userStories.count // return user story count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryCell
        cell.label.text = userStories[indexPath.row].title // display user story
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy shot, bro, thanks so much for taking the time to code this for me! This definitely has helped me and has gotten me off to the right start! I can't express how much I am grateful for this code. Thanks again, Ptit!